# Using a script inside component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, load

I am trying to use a payment modal through by a js script. I suspect that because I mount it on the `root` div it umounts all components. I want to load it conditionally, so a user can cancel it and open it later.

```js
    const loadScript = function (src) {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.async = false;
        tag.src = src;
        document.getElementById('something').appendChild(tag)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadScript('https://checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js')
        reepay.getId().then(data => {
            setReepayId(data.reepay.id)
        })
    }, []);

    const loadReepay = () => {
        return new window.Reepay.ModalCheckout(reepayId)
    }
```

```js
//how I am mounting it
{isPaying ? loadReepay() : <> </>}
```

I have tried using a HOC library, but I had issues with loading it conditionally but it did mount on the right component. I have also tried mounting it on a element inside the component `document.getElementById('element-id-inside-component').appendChild(tag)` however it still mounts on root and unmounts all my components. So I assume it is because it is instantiated over window `new window.Reepay.ModalCheckout(reepayId)`.

Here is a codesandbox illustrating the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-thunder-3h5vj?file=/src/App.js:0-1070

**EDIT**
Apparently the script does not return JSX...

```js
    const loadReepay = () => {
        new window.Reepay.ModalCheckout(reepayId)
    }
```

did the trick, if someone can provide an answer for people to come, then I'll mark it as answered and throw an upvote.

Comment: It's totally acceptable to reply to your own question and then mark it as the correct answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script did not return JSX, which is why I was not enable to render it inside the components render. so instead of returning the function, I simply had to call the constructor `new window.Reepay.ModalCheckout(reepayId)`.

```js
    const loadScript = function (src) {
        const element = document.createElement('script');
        element.async = false;
        element.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(element)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadScript('https://checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js')
        reepay.getId().then(data => {
            setReepayId(data.reepay.id)
        })
    }, []);

    const loadReepay = () => {
        const rp = new window.Reepay.ModalCheckout(reepayId)
        rp.addEventHandler(window.Reepay.Event.Cancel, function (data) {
            setIsPaying(false)
        });
    }
```